# Recode value in the column in unix with awk or sed

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In the following file, The values of 6th column for the rows who have values other than 1 or 2 in sixth column should be replaced with -9. How can I do it?
old.fam

```
18_0033 26210 0 0 1 1
18_0036 24595 0 0 1 2
18_0040 25563 0 0 1 
18_0041 35990 0 0 0 -8
18_0042 39398 0 0 0 -8
18_0045 21586 0 0 1 1
18_0050 22211 0 0 1 2
```

new.fam should be

```
18_0033 26210 0 0 1 1
18_0036 24595 0 0 1 2
18_0040 25563 0 0 1 -9
18_0041 35990 0 0 0 -9
18_0042 39398 0 0 0 -9
18_0045 21586 0 0 1 1
18_0050 22211 0 0 1 2
```

Edit: I used `cat old.fam | awk '{ if ($6==1 || $6==2) {print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 ;} else {print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " -9;}}'> new.fam`

Now the problem is the rows with replaced 6th column value (-9), does not have space separated FS between 5th and 6th column.

```
18_0033 26210 0 0 1 1
18_0036 24595 0 0 1 2
18_0040 25563 0 0 1-9
18_0041 35990 0 0 0-9
18_0042 39398 0 0 0-9
18_0045 21586 0 0 1 1
18_0050 22211 0 0 1 2
```

Comment: Looks like a typical case for `awk` or `sed`, plenty of posts about those commands here on the site.

Comment: i couldn't find any basic post for beginners. would you direct me to the one_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have something you can start working on:

```
cat test.txt | awk '{if ($6==1||$6==2) {print $1 " " $6;} else {print $1 " -9";}}'
```

The `awk` script does the following:

- check the value of the sixth column
- between both checks, there's the `awk` `||` logical OR operator

The rest of the script is obvious.

**Edit**
Apparently `awk` can't handle spaces, followed by numbers, so you might use this `awk` script:

```
awk '{ if ( $6==1|| $6==2) {print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 ;} else 
                           {print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " -9";}}'
```

(Mind the `$5 " -9"` at the end)

Comment: This is printing just 1st and 6th column of file. While i need all columns.

Comment: I'm just giving you a head start, the rest if up to you :-)

Comment: I used cat test.fam | awk '{ if ($6==1 || $6==2) {print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 ;} else {print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " -9;}}'> new.fam

Comment: The problem i am facing now is the FS between column 5 and 6 in new file are not space separated as originally file was. Can you give me some clue where i am wrong.

Comment: @Aryh: can you edit your original question and show the result you currently have? (I was expecting your command to work perfectly)

Comment: can you check editted post.